# Loop over object setters java

Tags: java, reflection

I have a POJO object and a collection of appropriate data.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestPojo {

private String name;
private String number;
private String id;
private String sex;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSex() {
    return sex;
}

public void setSex(String sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestPojo test = new TestPojo();

    List<String> sampleData = new ArrayList<>();
    sampleData.add("Bob");
    sampleData.add("641-613-623");
    sampleData.add("id-1451");
    sampleData.add("Male");

    test.setName(sampleData.get(0));
    test.setNumber(sampleData.get(1));
    test.setId(sampleData.get(2));
    test.setSex(sampleData.get(3));
    }
}
```

My question is how can i fill my POJO object with data in a loop? Is it posible to iterate all object setters and set data from List in appropriate places? I know that reflection can help in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an **simple example** to call **setters** via reflection (which needs to be adjusted):

[**if this is a good approach, is another question**. But to answer your question:]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    //this is only to demonstrate java reflection:
    Method[] publicMethods = TestPojo.class.getMethods(); //get all public methods
    TestPojo testObj = TestPojo.class.newInstance(); //when you have a default ctor (otherwise get constructors here)
    for (Method aMethod : publicMethods) //iterate over methods
    {
        //check name and parameter-count (mabye needs some more checks...paramter types can also be checked...)
        if (aMethod.getName().startsWith("set") && aMethod.getParameterCount() == 1)
        {
            Object[] parms = new Object[]{"test"}; //only one parm (can be multiple params)
            aMethod.invoke(testObj, parms); //call setter-method here
        }
    }
}
```

You can also save all setter-methods in an list/set for later re-use...
But as others already said, you have to be careful by doing so (using reflection)!

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can't easily - and you shouldn't.

You see, your POJO class offers some setters. All of them have a *distinct* meaning. Your first mistake is that all of these fields are **strings** in your model:

- gender is not a string. It would rather be an enum.
- "number" is not a string. It should rather be int/long/double (whatever the idea behind that property is)

In other words: you premise that "input" data is represented as array/list is already flawed.

The code you have written provides almost no helpful abstractions. So - instead of worrying how to call these setter methods in some loop context - you should rather step back and improve your model.

And hint: if this is really about populating POJO objects from string input - then get your string into JSON format, and use tools such as gson or jackson to do that (reflection based) mapping for you.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. This is just a sample POJO, in my case i have more than thirty fields of different types. That's why i do not want to fill it via constructor, but i want to fill it automatic in loop or in some other way.

Comment: It doesn't get better. Even POJOs should follow [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles. Having 30 fields in one class ... is a smell by itself already.

Answer (score 1):

"Iterating over methods" seems pretty much of a wrong idea in OO programming. You could simply add a **constructor** to your class setting all of your attributes, and then just call that constructor in a loop as desired to create new objects with data you desire.

In your class define:

```
public TestPojo(String name, String number, String id, String sex){

  this.name = name;
  this.number = number;
  this.id = id;
  this.sex = sex;

}
```

Also using a List makes no much sense here. I'd recommend using a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to then iterate over it in a for loop making proper calls of the above constructor.